# number of ordered pairs of integers $(x,y)$ satisfying the equation

Tags: diophantine-equations, systems-of-equations

I need to find the number of ordered pairs of integers $(x,y)$ satisfying this equation:

$$x^2 + 6x + y^2 = 4.$$

I have tried, and I think $x<0 . $

Is there a specific way to solve such equations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(x+3)^2 + y^2 = 13$. So $y^2 \leq 13$, and $|y| \leq \sqrt{13} \approx 3$. So you can find $y's$ and then $x's$. Note that they are integers so you can round down.

Comment: thanks you made it look easy. Is there any specific way to solve such equations? i dont think i would always be able to complete a square .

Comment: The general bivariate quadratic equation $ax^2+bxy+cy^2+dx+ey+f=0$ can (up to a few small cases) be rewritten in one of three forms by completing the square. Let $D=b^2-4ac$ denote the discriminant. If $D\neq0$ the equation can be rewritten as $v^2-Dw^2=n$ for unknown $v,w$. If $D<0$ (as was the case here) there is a finite number of solutions, each solution $(v,w)$ corresponds to an integral point on the ellipse $v^2+|D|w^2=n$.

Comment: If $D>0$ is not a square it reduces to a Pell-(type)equation $v^2-Dw^2=n$, which can be shown to have either $0$ or $\infty$ solutions. In particular if $n=1$ there are $\infty$ many. (If $D$ is a square you can factor as $(v+\sqrt Dw)(v-\sqrt Dw)=n$ and the problem reduces to finding divisors of $n$.) A solution $(v,w)$ geometrically corresponds to an integral point on the hyperbola $v^2-Dw^2=n$. If $D=0$ the quadratic reduces to a system of two simultaneous quadratic congruences, having either $0$ or $\infty$ solutions. Geometrically, solutions in this case are integral points on a parabola.

Answer (score 1):

it's an equation of a circle

http://www4b.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP145620gcidadhe55cg660000300770ba8ae7ghf3?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=59&w=200.&h=204.&cdf=RangeControl

these are integer answers :

$x=-6 , y=\pm2$

$x=-5 , y=\pm3$

$x=-1 , y=\pm3$

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2%2B6x%2By%5E2%3D4

Comment: 0, 2 is also an answer and is evident from circle. but i would like to know how to approach such questions where there are two variables in one equation

Comment: If it is a well-defined shape (like above) you can draw it but if it's not you can simplify the equation in terms of one variable (for example $y=x^2+5$) and substitute different values.

Answer (score 0):

We have $\displaystyle x^2+6x+y^2-4=0$

As $x$ is integer, so must be real $\implies \Delta=6^2-4(y^2-4)=4(13-y^2)\ge0\iff y^2\le13$