# Number of ordered pairs of integers $(x,y)$ satisfying the equation $x^2+6x+y^2=4$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

> Find the number of ordered pairs of integers $(x,y)$ satisfying the equation $x^2+6x+y^2=4.$

**My attempt**:

$x^2+6x+y^2=4$

$x^2+6x+9-9+y^2-4=0$

$(x+3)^2+y^2-13=0$

$(x+3)^2=13-y^2$

$x$ is required to be an integer. Therefore, let us consider $x$ as an integer.  Therefore $(x+3)$ is also an integer. Similarly $y$ is an integer.
Now, the square of any integer is a non-negative integer and more specifically a perfect square.

Therefore, $(x+3)^2$ and is a perfect square

$\implies 13-y^2$ is a perfect square

$\implies y=-3,+3,-2,+2$ (By trial and error method)

For $y=-3, +3$, there are two values of $x$ which are $x=-1,-5$

For $y=-2,+2$, there are two values of $x$ which are  $x=0,-6$

Hence there are eight ordered pairs in total: $(-1,-3),(-5,-3),(-1,+3),(-5,+3),(0,-2),(-6,-2),(0,+2),(-6,+2)$.

Therefore the number of ordered pairs of integers satifying the equation $x^2+6x+y^2=4$ is $8$.

**My problem**:

Is my method correct? Is there any other method to solve this problem?

Comment: did you write the solutions as $(y,x)$ without telling us?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner, corrected.

Comment: thanks; also, maybe you should indicate that $13-y^2\ge0$ limited your choice of $y$, so the extent of "trial and error" was small

Comment: @J.W.Tanner, I have indicated that by stating $13-y^2$ is a perfect square.

Comment: I mean you could say $\lfloor\sqrt{13}\rfloor=3\implies $ all the values of $y$ to try are in {$-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3$}

Comment: Your approach is fine and perhaps the only reasonable approach. No need to unnecessarily complicate things as if you were in middle school.

Comment: Same question as:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/878556/number-of-ordered-pairs-of-integers-x-y-satisfying-the-equation

Comment: Must be a homework problem at OP’s school or college

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly how I would do it, and (shouting out to uday) I am far beyond middle school.  Completing the square is a powerful tool for quadratic equations.